# How do I loot dead enemies and animals faster?

Tags: far-cry-4

To loot dead enemies or animals, I have to press <kbd>E</kbd> for a second over every single corpse. (If I do that too quickly, I switch my weapon unintentionally.)

Is it possible to make the looting process faster? e.g. Auto looting dead enemies or animals?

I am playing on the PC.

Comment: On the PS4 is no option for enabling that, I assume it's no different on PC. However, to prevent the awkward position till I can loot without switching weapons, I just pick the body up to loot it.

Comment: Some skills automatically loots enemies when you kill them with a takedown. I don't remember their name though. **Edit:** On the Tiger skill tree (left one) **Loot Takedown** - Cost – 2 Points - *Automatically loot an enemy while performing any takedown*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are three tips to decrease the annoyance of looting people, animals, and plants:

- You automatically loot any body you pick up. I don't think this requires a skill, but I didn't notice until about a third of the way through the game.
- As stated in the comments, the **Loot Takedown** skill allows you to loot any enemy simply by performing a takedown. While the skill says it works for *all* takedowns, those performed at a distance (knife, pistol, and grenade at least) don't seem to apply. I haven't paid enough attention to vehicle takedowns because they're just too much fun. \o/
- Hold the interaction key as you run up to dead people, animals, and plants to minimize the chance of accidentally switching weapons. Make sure to look down at the object and stop over it (seems to help for bodies). It's not fool-proof for avoiding weapon swaps, but it works about 95% of the time for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can turn off the looting animations in Options » General » Gameplay to make looting faster.

[image: screenshot of options toggle mentioned above]

Comment: This is helpful, but is not a direct answer. So I'll help you by not flagging it, but just downvoting.

Comment: @ardaozkal The question seems like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/162827). In the question, OP wants to make looting faster and asked for an 'auto-loot' solution. But there could be other, possibly better solutions to make looting faster, such as the one suggested by this answer and the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to automatically do this.

But I wish there was. I personally stopped looting people and animals **once I crossed the bridge**. At this point, I opened chests only, and avoided the garbage on enemies, and I had all the the animal skin missions completed except the Kyrat Fashion Week quests.

You're going to notice that throwing meat to attract animals, is either going to be ineffective at most times because the forces in that base are much stronger, or none will simply even show up. So I just stopped looting animals unless 4 attacked me at the same time and I could pick them up quickly and refill my stock, otherwise I avoided animals at all costs.